# Improving performance of Elasticsearch exists query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following query, which finds records that do not contain any of the following fields: `timestamp_login`, `timestamp_logout`, `timestamp_signup` and groups by `user_city`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "timestamp_login"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "timestamp_logout"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "timestamp_signup"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_item": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['user_city.keyword'].value?.toLowerCase()",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    },
    "distinct_terms": {
      "cardinality": {
        "script": "doc['user_city.keyword'].value?.toLowerCase()"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

However, the query often times out. Is there a more efficient way to pull records where a list of fields are missing? Also, I'm running ES 5.6.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how many documents are you running this query on? what's your hardware spec?

Comment: 1.5 billion docs. not sure about the hardware spec, I can find out. anything in particular about the hardware you're interested in?

Comment: Are you in control of the indexing? any chance to add a flag on docs that don't have any of those three fields? the query would be a single term query instead of three exists.

Comment: yes, I'm in control of the indexing. I was thinking along the same lines. e.g. adding a "tags" array and doing a scripted update so that whenever one of the timestamps get's populated, we add a corresponding tag to the array. then using a terms query to filter records that have / don't have the corresponding tags

Comment: You should try and see how it goes

Comment: okay, I'm getting much better read performance after adding a "tags" array, and using a terms query to check the existence of certain tags :)